# Hide label x-axis but still keep vertical axis jquery flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, flot

I'm finding about `jquery flot`. And i want to hide label `x-axis` but i want to keep `vertical axis`.

Here my demo code: [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a0rn86ej/9/)

Here my picture what i expected (remove all lable `x-axis`).
[image]

Hope everybody can help me. Thank you very much.

**Update**:

I updated my code as `labelWidth` and `labelHeight`, but it it still appear.

```
xaxis: {
  mode: "time",
  timezone: "browser",
  ticks: 6,
  labelWidth: 0,
  labelHeight: 0,
  ticks: [
    now_hour,
    now_hour + 3600000*1,
    now_hour + 3600000*2,
    now_hour + 3600000*3,
    now_hour + 3600000*4,
    now_hour + 3600000*5,
    now_hour + 3600000*6 
  ],
  timeformat: "%H:%M"
}
```

**Update**: Follow as Stargazer's answer. It worked as well.

We just update `css`.

```
.tickLabels .xAxis { 
 color:transparent !important; 
}
```

Comment: Look in the documentation for labelHeight and labelWidth, if you set these to zero it should not appear.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i updated as your suggestion, but it still appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to .css file:

```
.tickLabels .xAxis { 
  color:transparent !important; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/mb3gn9Lv/22/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, label `x-axis` didn't appear, but `vertical axis` didn't appear. I want to display `vertical axis`.

Comment: Then use css property: 
.tickLabels .xAxis {
  color:transparent !important;
}
I've update a fiddle. Look [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/mb3gn9Lv/22/)

Comment: Yes, your solution was great. I think you should update your answer and i will vote your answer which is great. One again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about previous versions but v3.0.0 this works:

```
  xaxis: {
    showTickLabels: 'none'
  }
```

Check the source code of this expample https://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-labels/index.html